# Creating Java standard data structure with a poll() or pop() (or any other equivalent) from varargs elements?

Tags: java, collections

Is there any better way of creating a Java data structure with a `poll()` or `pop()` (or any other equivalent) from a varargs (without dependencies of auxiliary libraries)?

```java
Queue<String> q = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
q.poll(); // -> "A"
q.poll(); // -> "B"
...
```

**Notice** it is not mandatory to be a `Queue` it can be any kind of standard Java data structure that provides a method to retrieves and remove the head element.

Comment: Is the way you've shown not good enough?

Comment: IMHO it is too verbose!

Comment: @MiguelGamboa well, that's Java for you. There is no shorter way to do this. If you added a static import, it would only be `(asList("a"...))`, but that's hardly better.

Comment: You can save a few characters by doing it as `Queue q = new ArrayDeque<>(List.of("A", "B", "C"));`

Comment: how would your desired codes look like? you can probably write your own wrapper by following that.

Comment: `Queue<String> q = new ArrayDeque<>(); Collections.addAll(q, "A", "B", "C");` When you question is only about source code compactness, `var q = new ArrayDeque<>(List.of("A", "B", "C"));`